# gdb cannot index into an array and print value

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

I have an object `a` of type `vector<char>`. I know it is 10 elements long. But, when I do `p a[5]` in gdb, I get an error saying gdb could not resolve symbol `operator[]`.

```
void foo()
{
    vector<char> a (10, 10); // put a breakpoint here.
}
```

Could you please suggest me a way to print the value at index in gdb? Right now, I did something really lame -

`char c1=a[1]; char c2 = a[2]; char c3 = a[3]; // ... so on and forth`

Can I trust the values in `c1`, `c2`, etc

P.S. I have built my code with DEBUG symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works without issues with gdb 7.11.1

```
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400bd3: file t.C, line 6.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/t 
Missing separate debuginfos, use: dnf debuginfo-install glibc-2.23.1-8.fc24.x86_64

Breakpoint 1, main () at t.C:6
6       std::vector<char> a={'a','b','c','d','e','f'};
Missing separate debuginfos, use: dnf debuginfo-install libgcc-6.1.1-3.fc24.x86_64 libstdc++-6.1.1-3.fc24.x86_64
(gdb) n
8       std::cout << "Ok" << std::endl;
(gdb) p a
$1 = std::vector of length 6, capacity 6 = {97 'a', 98 'b', 99 'c', 100 'd', 
  101 'e', 102 'f'}
(gdb) p a[2]
$2 = 99 'c'
```

The answer here is to update to the current version of gcc and gdb.

Comment: Did you write a custom pretty printer?

Comment: No. Stock gdb, on Fedora 24. No customizations.

Answer (score 2):

A vector is not the same as an array or a pointer. A vector typically has a pointer to the start, which you can use to access elements. Try something like this

```
p *(a._M_impl._M_start+5)
```

Here I'm accessing the pointer to the start of the array, adding 5 to get the element at index 5.

Comment: Note that `a._M_impl._M_start[5]` works as well, and it's possible to use tab-completion.